# How to dynamically pass data parameter in a jquery ajax call (multiple arrays of data)

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have this ajax code:

```
return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "somefile.php",
        cache:false,
        data: { "yfilter": $("#yearFilter").serializeArray(),
            "gfilter": $("#genreFilter").serializeArray() },
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data){
            alert("success");
        }
```

This works fine, but I need to pass the data parameter dynamically. For now I need the above data parameter content and a single string.

How do I pass this dynamically? / How do I store it in a variable and pass it to the "data:" field?

```
 { "yfilter": $("#yearFilter").serializeArray(),
    "gfilter": $("#genreFilter").serializeArray() }
```

I tried JSON.stringify I I couldn't get it to work probably due to the data being an array.

The year and genre arrays are coming directly from the jquery drop down menu. It is selected like by it's #id like so "$("#yearFilter")". This is the select form element.

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="yearFilter[]" class="filterChange" id="yearFilter">
```

**What I need at the base level is:**

```
var someData = "";


    if(...){
        someData = { "yfilter": $("#yearFilter").serializeArray(),
                "gfilter": $("#genreFilter").serializeArray() };
    }
    else if(...){
        someData = "sampleString";
    }
```

And in ajax call:

```
...
data: someData,
...
```

Comment: what do you mean by dynamically..?

Comment: I mean that I need to pass a variable with either the year/genre data or a single string to the data field depending what content I want displayed.

Comment: Create a array and send none if not present ?

Comment: Yes, but the issue is that I am passing 2 arrays: genre and year.

Comment: are you using that in `form`?

Comment: Not a form as such but it is a selection a user can make and it will be either year/ genre combo or it will be another non-user call to get similar movies (only movie id will be passed). I want to reuse this ajax call as other than data and url it is identical.

Comment: sounds more like you are having coordination issue with making ajax array match php `$_POST`. Provide `$_Post` format you expect also. You can send array to php in mutliple formats including JSON, or just send the array you have

Comment: also shoudln't need `traditional:false` option

Comment: The arrays are actually coming from selecting html element by #id as you can see, so the php post doesn't really come into play here. The php file return "echo json_encode($moviesArray);"which is the movie info that is then displayed.

Comment: last comment really confuses what the problem is?? Please be explicit and detailed about what the actual issue is..and what is or isn't working or what needs to happen

Comment: You should, like you said, pass a json object. can you show what is the data? json.stringify should work.

Comment: Ok, I want to pass different data to "data:" of the ajax call. First option I want to pass is what you see in the question(genre and year filter arrays). The second option I want to pass is a simple string(something like "data: { similarMovie: movieIdVariable }")

Comment: @DominicM why is JSON.stringify fails? can you show the data you are trying to stringify?

Comment: are you only needing the ultra simple part of creating a variable of either /or and passing that variable to data of ajax?

Comment: I am not sure why stringify fails exactly, but can it even handle arrays like so: "$("#yearFilter").serializeArray()"?

Comment: @charlietfl well yes, but I tried that and it doesnt pass the data if I just move the current data parameters into a variable(with appropriate concat).

Comment: can what handle arrays? AJAX yes, php yes. As stated in comments above but you replied `$_POST` has nothing to do with it except `$_POST` has to be set up to manage format you send

Comment: to get array of select just use `val()` method

Comment: I meant JSON.stringify. The post/php works with the current example in the answer so it is not the problem right now. the problem is being able to pass the current example data contents dynamically (eg. via a variable as opposed to having the data directly in the "data:" field)

Comment: @charlietfl I don't think I need val, it works as it is now (I am selecting by id). The serialiseArray is to make it work with jquery/ajax call.

Comment: Please, see edit for clarification.

Comment: OK.. edit will work as is. What part doesn't work?

Comment: Ok, I feel bad now for since it does indeed work, I must have had an extra comma or character before when I tried this as I got compiler errors thinking it was the format with quotes and {} that tripped it up. Really sorry for wasting everyone's time :-)  Should I delete this Q or leave it?

Comment: Highly suggest using browser console to look at errors!! And being more clear on exactly what problem is next time

Comment: Actually I tried Console in Chrome but nothing was shown and not because of absence of data since alert gave [object]. Request were shown but no data printed on the console tab anywhere other than the expected html code. Edit: I realize now you ddn't mean Console(); but rather just the errors tab, in which case I did and no error were reported.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I have an idea what you want but post has been overly complicated by extraneous issues like json stringify . Here's a function that could be used in several places eleswhere in your code to make one type of AJAX call or another.

You would then perhaps have several buttons and call the function within handlers for each type of button and change the argument passed to function

```
doAjax('someval');/* use in button 1*/
doAjax('someOtherval');/* use in button 2*/



function doAjax(arg) {

    var someData = "";
    if (arg == 'someval') {
        someData = {
            "yfilter": $("#yearFilter").val(),
            "gfilter": $("#genreFilter").val()
        };
    } else {
        someData = "sampleString";
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "somefile.php",
        cache: false,
        data: someData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if (arg == 'someval') {
                alert("success 1");
            } else {
                alert("success 2");
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Agreed, I assumed it couldn't be achieved by simply moving the current arrays in the same format to a variable. Thanks for getting to the bottom of it!

Answer (score 1):

Hope I've understood what you're asking for.
You could do something like this:

```
var parameters = {};
if (...) {
    parameters = $("#yearFilter").serializeArray();
}
if () {
    parameters = $("#genreFilter").serializeArray();
}
```

and then replace the line:

```
parameters: { "yfilter": $("#yearFilter").serializeArray(),
              "gfilter": $("#genreFilter").serializeArray() },
```

with:

```
data: parameters,
```

Comment: ...but i'm not sure if this was what you were asking for!

Comment: It's close but it won't work because I need to pass BOTH year and genre arrays at the same time :)

Answer (score 0):

JSON type should be best option for dynamically data. push whatever data you wish to inside json like shown below, Hence create your json dynamically and send as ajax data.

```
var employees = {
    accounting: [],
    dept: "HR"
}; 

employees.accounting.push({ 
   "firstName" : item.firstName,
   "lastName"  : item.lastName,
   "age"       : item.age 
});


$.ajax({
        url: POSTURL,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data : employees,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (results)
        {

        },
        error: function (results)
        {
            jQuery.error(String.format("Status Code: {0}, ", results.status, results.statusText));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
someData = JSON.stringify({ yfilter: $("#yearFilter").val(), gfilter: $("#genreFilter").val() });
```

It will work.